# Find a line and replace a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a text file with several lines. I will be using sed to replace a comma separated value in one of those lines. There is an ID at the beginning of each line (Record ID essentially). I need to identify the right line to do the modification to by using the ID. I had considered reading in the file line by line until I find it, but I was curious is there is another way?

Comment: sed is perfect for that. Hard to be more specific without more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/^theID,/s/oldValue/newValue/'
```

Comment: This is wrong, what about if your current line id is 123 and the given id is 2 ?

Comment: good point - updated, given that the record ID is at the start of the line and is followed by a , since the file is CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Awk or Perl might be better for this particular case

here this will replace "foo" with "bar" in your file at the line which is matched by yourID in the first column

```
awk -F ',' '/yourID/ {gsub("foo", "bar", $2); print}' fileIn > fileOut
```

or perl oneliners, here swaps the 3rd column with "bar" where line matches with yourID in the first column.

```
perl -F',' -lane 'if(@F[0] =~ m/yourID/){ @F[2] = "bar"; print(join(", ", @F))}' fileIn > fileOut
```

Comment: Better use `eq` instead of `m//` !

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions seems not reliable (the id isn't tested properly), so this is my [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) way to do it :

```
$ cat file
001,a,b,c
002,a2,b2,c2

$ perl -F, -lane '$F[0] eq "002" and $F[1] = "z"; print join ",", @F' file
001,a,b,c
002,z,b2,c2
```

If you want to replace ths file *in-place*, you can add the `-i` switch, so :

```
$ perl -i -F, -lane '$F[0] eq "002" and $F[1] = "z"; print join ",", @F' file
```

But a proper CSV like perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV) parser should be used here actually.